# why "breakpoint at futex" and write() affect each other in GDB

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, mutex, futex

When I use gdb to debug futex locks with output, the program gets stuck in a weird loop.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
volatile int counter(0); // non-atomic counter
std::mutex mtx;
void increases10k(){
        for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
                sleep(1);
                std::cout << "The ID of this thread is: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
                std::cout  << counter <<std::endl;
                mux.lock();
                ++counter;
                std::cout  << counter <<std::endl;
                mtx.unlock();
        }
}
int main(int argc,char **argv){
        std::thread threads[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                threads[i]=std::thread(increases10k);
        for(auto& th:threads)
                th.join();
        std::cout << " successful increases of the counter " << counter <<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I use gdb command `catch system futex` to check system call futex.

Then I used `c` to keep the program running, **but the program stopped output** and got stuck in a weird call and ret loop.

```
Thread 8 "a.out" hit Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall futex), __lll_lock_wait_private ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
95      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
[Switching to Thread 0x7f0db5ffb700 (LWP 8923)]

Thread 9 "a.out" hit Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall futex), __lll_lock_wait_private ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
95      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
[Switching to Thread 0x7f0db7fff700 (LWP 8919)]

Thread 3 "a.out" hit Catchpoint 1 (returned from syscall futex), __lll_lock_wait_private ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
95      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
.........
```

It's endless.  I also noticed that a thread was stuck in write(), but pressing c couldn't get it to continue.

```
Id   Target Id         Frame
  1    Thread 0x7f0dbe8ac5c0 (LWP 8915) "a.out" 0x00007f0dbe48a6dd in pthread_join (threadid=139696990869248, thread_return=0x0)
    at pthread_join.c:90
  2    Thread 0x7f0dbd845700 (LWP 8916) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  3    Thread 0x7f0dbd044700 (LWP 8917) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  4    Thread 0x7f0dbc843700 (LWP 8918) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  5    Thread 0x7f0db7fff700 (LWP 8919) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  6    Thread 0x7f0db77fe700 (LWP 8920) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  7    Thread 0x7f0db6ffd700 (LWP 8921) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  8    Thread 0x7f0db67fc700 (LWP 8922) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  9    Thread 0x7f0db5ffb700 (LWP 8923) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
* 10   Thread 0x7f0db57fa700 (LWP 8924) "a.out" 0x00007f0dbd92198d in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  11   Thread 0x7f0db4ff9700 (LWP 8925) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
```

When I comment out the output, the program works fine using `c` in gdb.

I don't understand why "breakpoint at futex" and write() affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use gdb to debug futex locks

Note that debugging futex locks (or any other multithreading issues) with GDB is ~impossible -- you need to have the program correct by construction.

About the only debugging you *could* do is understand where the program is after it deadlocks.

> It's endless

What did you expect? Every call to `mux.lock()` and `mux.unlock()` *may* execute a `futex` call, and you are doing 2 * 10 * 100'000'000 of them (there is an additional factor of 2 because GDB stops on *entry* and *exit* from system call).

*Of course* you are going to be stuck there forever.

http://xyproblem.info seems appropriate here.

Comment: Theoretically every time you enter the lock, execute
```
++counter;
std::cout  << counter <<std::endl;
```
Theoretically, the current counter value should be printed, but it is not. Using `p counter` also confirms that the value of `counter` has not changed.
If I comment out all the output and use `p counter`, I can see that `counter` continues to grow as I press `c`